# Have page's parent render function update on button click in Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework, dynamic-routing

I've just started using Phoenix to create a set of basic interactive coding tutorials -- I've run into a bit of a barrier, and wondered if anyone can help.

I currently have a template like this:

**linux.html.eex**

```
<div class="tutorials-box tutorials-linux-box">
  <div class="left-tutorials-box left-tutorials-linux-box">
    <h2 class="content-subheader linux-content-subheader">Linux</h2>
    <%= render MyAppWeb.TutorialsView, "linux/1-1.html", conn: @conn %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a set of tutorials in the linux template sub-directory, ordered chronologically:

```
/templates/tutorials/linux/1-1.html.eex
/templates/tutorials/linux/1-2.html.eex
/templates/tutorials/linux/1-3.html.eex
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have the user click a button in each subview (i.e. 1-1.html.eex), and have the render function on the parent view (linux.html.eex) update to the next tutorial. The way I was thinking of doing this is by updating a variables on button click and then piping the variable into the render function, but I'm not sure how to do this in Phoenix and I couldn't find an example in the documentation. If possible I'd also like the url to show the tutorial number, like `/tutorials/linux/1-1.html`. Currently it shows only `/tutorials/linux`.

Comment: Just pass a chapter to the template: `<%= render MyAppWeb.TutorialsView, "linux/1-#{@assigns[:chapter]}.html", conn: @conn %>` from your controller.

Comment: Using this with `def linux(conn, _params) do chapter = "1" render conn, "linux.html", chapter: chapter end` in the controller outputs `assign @assigns not available in eex template`

Comment: IIRC `assigns` is a normal variable in EEx templates so try without `@`

Comment: that worked, narrowtux; feel free to put in an answer